# How to connect Airbyte with Airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have Airflow and Airbyte installed locally with Docker. I want to set a connection in Airflow to connect Airbyte. I read the Airbyte docs and did exactly what it says but I am getting error. I have configured Airflow's docker compose yaml to install necessary packages.

```
ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:- apache-airflow-providers-http apache-airflow-providers-airbyte apache-airflow-providers-airbyte[http]}
```

My Airflow executor is CeleryExecutor

In Airflow I configured the connection how excatly the Airbyte's docs says. I also tried with Conn Type: Airbyte but still getting the error.

[image]

The error says:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8001): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v1/health (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f30e9e4fb10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

Comment: Is the error the same if you replace `localhost`with `host.docker.internal` ?

Comment: Now it says "401: Unauthorized". How can I find the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Finally got around to testing this. For me using the Airbyte connection type that comes with the [Airbyte provider](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/airbyte) plus including the username and password (default is "airbyte"/"password") worked with Airflow 2.5.1 and Airbyte provider 3.2.0.

On the Airbyte side I followed [their getting started docs](https://github.com/airbytehq/airbyte/blob/master/docs/quickstart/getting-started.md).

[image: Airbyte Connection]

Answer (score 1):

Airbyte's blog covers this scenario and how to get it working: https://airbyte.com/tutorials/how-to-use-airflow-and-airbyte-together

- Disclaimer, I am the author of that article.

Comment: Hi Alexander. Anyway to add dbt on this project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Airflow through Docker, when passing "localhost", it points to the Docker container itself.

Point the Airflow connection to your local machine's IP address. If you are using Ubuntu, you can use the command:

```
hostname -I
```

to obtain your IP address.